# Can I concatenate aliases in YAML?

Tags: yaml

I would like to do something like:

```
opt-flags   : &opt_flags -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
dbg-flags   : &dbg_flags -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
common-flags: &common    -DENABLE_EXAMPLES=ON -DENABLE_TESTS=ON 

# concatenate previous definitions to create composed definitions
dbg: *common *dbg_flags   
opt: *common *opt_flags
```

This doesn't work directly.  Is it possible to do something equivalent to this in YAML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot do that, an alias replaces a complete node.

However if you are dealing with mappings, you can use the [merge key language-independent type](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) if your parser supports it to combine multiple sets of keys into a new mapping:

```
opt-flags   : &opt_flags -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
dbg-flags   : &dbg_flags -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
common-flags: &common    -DENABLE_EXAMPLES=ON -DENABLE_TESTS=ON 

dbg:
  << : [*common_flags, *dbg_flags]
opt:
  << : [*common_flags, *opt_flags]
```

This however will make two entries each, and not concatenate the strings scalars that are anchored, and will need a program that can combine the multiple values, *for which the ordering is not guaranteed*.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately in 2022 you still cannot concatenate or join aliases with other aliases or strings. In addition to the accepted answer, there is another syntax which works the same but is easier to read IMO (this works in docker-compose btw):

```yaml
x-foo: &foo
  VAR1: value1
x-bar: &bar
  VAR2: value2

foobar:
  <<: 
    - *foo
    - *bar

# foobar:
#   VAR1: value1
#   VAR2: value2
```

Also worth noting that you can nest anchors too:

```yaml
x-foo: &foo
  VAR1: value1
  bar: &bar
    VAR2: value2

foobar:
  <<: *foo
  bing:
    <<: *bar
    VAR3: value3

# foobar: 
#   VAR1: value1
#   bing: 
#     VAR2: value2
#     VAR3: value3
```

Comment: Does anyone quickly have a link where the first method is defined in the YAML specs? Is it officially supported to have multiple `<<` on the same level?

Comment: I've been using multiple `<<` for over a year now in basically all of my compose files. While the spec doesn't provide examples, the `*bar` part is an alias which refers to the `&bar` anchor. That basically means "replace `*bar` with the contents of `&bar`".

Comment: True. The problem I'm facing is not parsing YAML but linters and beautifiers that occasionally complain about multiple <<. Especially `yamlfmt`. I am looking for a spec that says that multiple << are supported in order to have some weight, some proof, when opening a bug report.

Comment: Hmm, I found [this page on merge keys](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) which says to put multiple aliases in a sequence (array). I also found [this SO answer] which suggests the same. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Will this make the expanded anchors appear on the same level as when using no arrays?

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer above (using array syntax) or my answer (using multiple merge keys `<<`) should both result in the same thing. My solution is easier to read and reason about IMO, but some YAML parsers might not like it... and they're not technically _"wrong"_. The array syntax in the accepted answer has the widest amount of interoperability - so if you are sharing YAML configs with different teams and different systems, use the array syntax.